# OpenGL 4.4 on Linux

Tags: linux, opengl

I want to learn OpenGL development and I am running Linux Mint.  Khronos.org says the following:

`The OpenGL 4.4 and OpenGL Shading Language 4.40 Specifications were released on July 22, 2013.`

As far as I understand Mesa is the OpenGL implementation for Linux but it is only one version 3.1 I believe.  My question is, can I develop OpenGL 4.4 apps in the Linux environment or do I have to use Mesa's 3.1 version?

Comment: You can use proprietary drivers.

Comment: Mesa's actually far more than a GL implementation. It serves as a front-end for some official drivers from the likes of Intel, for instance. So it is impossible to say for sure what needs to be done here - your actual GPU would help.

Answer (score 2):

You can *develop* OpenGL 4.4 software by #including the glext.h file from http://www.opengl.org/registry/

You can *run* OpenGL 4.4 software by using hardware drivers that implement the [OpenGL 4.4 specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf) and a GPU that supports the necessary hardware features. In practical terms, this means you need an AMD or Nvidia GPU that supports Direct3D 11 and very recent proprietary (closed-source) drivers from the GPU vendor.

Mesa3d is the  open-source driver framework, with partial support for OpenGL 4.x. The proprietary drivers from AMD and Nvidia replace Mesa3d with their own OpenGL implementation.

Note that you can *develop* OpenGL 4.4 software even if your system cannot *run* said software.

Comment: I just got an HP with Radeon HD 8750M graphics.  The driver supports OpenGL 4.4.  I also got the OpenGL Programming Guide 4.3.  I'm trying to run the `triangles.cpp` program in the first chapter.  Besides glext.h is there any libraries I need to link to?

Comment: Use the included makefile to build (open a terminal and type `make`). You can download the source code from http://www.opengl-redbook.com/Code/oglpg-8th-edition.zip

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to run `triangles.cpp`.  I got the book's source code and placed the GL and GL3 folders inside /usr/include.  From the OpenGL superbible I'm compiling with this command `g++ triangles.cpp -lGL -lX11 -lXi -lglut -lGLU -lm` but I'm getting errors that __glew* functions are undefined.  Do I need to get a GLEW library?

Comment: You are not linking with glew (-lGLEW or so). You can install GLEW through your package manager, or use the version that is bundled in oglpg.

Answer (score 0):

AMD and NVIDIA proprietary drivers are probably the only drivers on Linux supporting OpenGL 4.4.

Comment: Yes, but can I develop an OpenGL 4.4 app this way?

Comment: @MichaelGlaz: That question makes no sense whatsoever. Like I said in my comment, your available GL version depends on the installed hardware. Intel's drivers go through Mesa and currently implement OpenGL 3.3 on capable hardware, on other hardware Mesa does not support 3.3. Likewise, using the proprietary drivers from NV or AMD will only get you OpenGL 4.x if your hardware actually supports it. Older GPUs will limit you to 3.3 or older.

Comment: So I'm kind of confused. On the Mesa site it says `Mesa 10.1 implements the OpenGL 3.3 API`.  I do have an NVIDIA card.  Are you saying NVIDIA has an implementation of the 4.x API?  If so, which NVIDIA libraries do I #include to be able to code an OpenGL 4.x app?

Comment: If you develop against the Mesa OpenGL 3 API, your program will (should) run on any system with an OpenGL 3 or better libGL, including Mesa, ATI, or NVIDIA. If you want to develop for OpenGL 4, you will currently need an ATI or NVIDIA binary driver and SDK.